# "trait core::ops::Fn<(Request, Response)> is not implemented" for a closure when passing a connection pool to a Hyper handler

Tags: rust, traits, hyper

I'm trying to build a small web service in Rust using [Hyper](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper) and [r2d2](https://github.com/sfackler/r2d2), but I'm running into some issues concerning traits. I'm unable to parse the error message thrown by the compiler, so I was hoping someone could help me out.

Consider the following code:

```
extern crate hyper;
extern crate postgres;
extern crate r2d2;
extern crate r2d2_postgres;

use hyper::Server;
use hyper::server::{Request,Response,Handler};
use r2d2_postgres::{SslMode, PostgresConnectionManager};
use r2d2::{Pool, PooledConnection};
use postgres::{Connection};

fn connect() -> Pool<PostgresConnectionManager>{
    let config = r2d2::Config::default();
    let conns = "postgres://abc:abc@localhost/abc";
    let manager = PostgresConnectionManager::new(conns, SslMode::None).unwrap();
    let pool = r2d2::Pool::new(config, manager).unwrap();
    return pool;
}

fn hello(pool: Pool<PostgresConnectionManager>, req: Request, res: Response) {
    res.send(b"Hello world").unwrap();
}

fn main() {
    let pool = connect();
    let dispatch = move |req: Request, res: Response| hello(pool, req, res);
    Server::http("127.0.0.1:3000").unwrap().handle(dispatch).unwrap();
}
```

My goal is to use `pool` in the function `hello`. By using closures, I thought, I could pass an environment variable wile still living up to the expectations Hyper has. Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
src/main.rs:28:45: 28:61 error: the trait `for<'r, 'r, 'r> core::ops::Fn<(hyper::server::request::Request<'r, 'r>, hyper::server::response::Response<'r>)>` is not implemented for the type `[closure@src/main.rs:27:20: 27:76 pool:r2d2::Pool<r2d2_postgres::PostgresConnectionManager>]` [E0277]
src/main.rs:28     Server::http("127.0.0.1:3000").unwrap().handle(dispatch).unwrap();
                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:28:45: 28:61 help: run `rustc --explain E0277` to see a detailed explanation
error: aborting due to previous error
```

It depends on the type of `pool`. If I try to pass an `i64` for example, it's all swell and the compiler doesn't complain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the source for hyper, we can see for which closures the required trait is implemented:

```
impl<F> Handler for F where F: Fn(Request, Response<Fresh>), F: Sync + Send {
    fn handle<'a, 'k>(&'a self, req: Request<'a, 'k>, res: Response<'a, Fresh>) {
        self(req, res)
    }
}
```

This means your closure needs to implement `Fn(Request, Response) + Sync + Send` for the `Handler` trait to be implemented for you. Otherwise, you need to implement it yourself. Since your closure takes `pool` by value, it only implements `FnOnce(Request, Response)` (can only be called once as `pool` gets moved into the function).

To fix this, take an immutable reference to the pool instead so that your function can be called multiple times (i.e. implements `Fn(Request, Response)`).

```
fn hello(pool: &Pool<PostgresConnectionManager>, req: Request, res: Response) {
    res.send(b"Hello world").unwrap();
}

fn main() {
    let pool = connect();
    let dispatch = move |req: Request, res: Response| hello(&pool, req, res);
    Server::http("127.0.0.1:3000").unwrap().handle(dispatch).unwrap();
}
```

---

N.B. The trait `Fn(Request, Response)` is syntactic sugar for the higher-rank trait bound `for<'r> Fn(Request<'r,'r>, Response<'r>)`. This is because `Request` and `Response` are both generic on a lifetime and so your function must handle `Request`s and `Response`s of *any* lifetime.